# How to write a function for a separate post template that will be applied by category? Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Good afternoon, there is such a task. There are 2 categories, and only for posts of these 2 categories one post template should be used. Now I use this code, but it does not fit, I have to create a separate template for each category. (And you need to have 1 template).

```
add_filter('single_template', 'check_for_category_single_template');
    function check_for_category_single_template( $t ){
        foreach( (array) get_the_category() as $cat ){
            if ( file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH . "/single-category-{$cat->slug}.php") ) return TEMPLATEPATH . "/single-category-{$cat->slug}.php";
            if($cat->parent){
                $cat = get_the_category_by_ID( $cat->parent );
                if ( file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH . "/single-category-{$cat->slug}.php") ) return TEMPLATEPATH . "/single-category-{$cat->slug}.php";
            }
        }
        return $t;
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide an example. The way it is described is a bit confusing for me.

Comment: I have 2 categories. For posts from these categories need to make a custom template.@juan

Comment: For example, I have 3 categories: Slides, Pipe, dude. 5 posts are in the category of Slides, Pipe. 5 posts are in the category of dude. For posts categories Slides, the Pipe you want to display a custom template @juan

Comment: Excuse me for the translation @juan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function with the changes below whould work.

I assume you have TEMPLATEPATH already defined.

Also you will need to go to the Slides and Pipe Category and get the slugs for those two categories.

If they are different from 'slides' and 'pipe' make the changes below for them to match.

The template you create must have this name: *single-category-slide_or_pipe.php*

```
add_filter('single_template', 'check_for_category_single_template');
function check_for_category_single_template( $t ){
        foreach( (array) get_the_category() as $cat ){
            if($cat->slug === 'slides' || $cat->slug === 'pipe'){
                if ( file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH . "/single-category-slide_or_pipe.php") ){
                    return TEMPLATEPATH . "/single-category-slide_or_pipe.php";
                }
            }
        }
        return $t;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try and write you